# VScode won't run Python scripts anymore, going on the last 2 weeks and can't figure it out

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Not sure what changed but now if I try to run any --------.py file, I get this response.

```
**test.py : The term 'test.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ test.py
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (test.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException   Suggestion [3,General]: The command test.py was not found, but does exist in the
current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the
current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type:
".\test.py". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more
details.**
```

I've been learning and running Python over the last few months, and now something changed and can't run Python files.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you try ```.\test.py```?

Comment: How have you been running `test.py`? (BTW, I'd recommend Python in WSL rather than in the Windows shell)

Answer (score 0):

You could not run the python file directly.

You need to run it like this: `python test.py`.

If you are using the VSCode and want to run the python file. Press `F5` directly and follows the instructions. You could look into [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for help.

Comment: @Jeff If it does not work, please let me know.